# Ruby on Rails, saving to database with proper date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, internationalization, date-formatting

I am currently fighting with Rails internationalization and date formats.

I'm working on an app that will eventually be deployed for the U.S market as well as English and French Canadian markets.

With the date format being yyyy-mm-dd (ie 2017-02-24) in the Postgresql database, when I wanted to retrieve a date from the database and display it in a view or form, I would use the following approach.

When displaying the date I would use:

```
<h5><%=p.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y - %l:%M:%S %p")%></h5>
```

When handling them in forms, I would retrieve the date in the controller and then do:

```
@receivable.date_posted = Date.today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

And then it would show using the proper format in the form.
In the form I have a datepicker that selects the date in the proper m/d/yyyy format.

And then, once the form was submitted, I had to get the date from the params (which was in m/d/yyyy) format and reformat it into the proper database date format yyyy-mm-dd like this:

```
@receivable.date_posted = Date.strptime(params[:date_posted],"%m/%d/%Y")
```

I quickly realized that this would be a little bit crazy once I try to implement the Canadian date formats so I have looked into internationalization.

I have created the proper locales for the markets and now use the following when I want to display the proper date format

However, I still find myself puzzled as to what to do when handling dates in forms.

Now I don't have to format the date when retrieving the record and I use the following in the form.

```
<%= f.text_field :date_posted, :value => (l f.object.date_posted, format: :notime), class: "form-control input-sm text-center",id: "receivable_date_posted", style: "display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width: 60%; margin: 0 5px 0 0;"%>
```

But that doesn't solve my problem when I try to update or create the record in the proper controller event because the date still comes from the params in the m/d/yyyy format (or another format depending on the locale).

Is there a simple way to save a date in the proper database format without having to convert the date (which potentially means convert the date for every possible date format depending on the locale?)

Comment: Can your date picker display one format but store another in the form? That way you can work with ISO8601 formats (YYYY-MM-DD) everywhere except at the very edges of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PostgreSQL provide you its date format i.e: "2017-02-24"
and your goal is to format it to print: "24/02/2017"
try this

```
postgres_date = "2017-02-24"

date_goal = Date.parse(postgres_date).strftime("%m-%d-%Y").gsub('-', '/')
```

> output => "02/24/2017"

or

```
date_goal = Date.parse(postgres_date).strftime("%m-%d-%Y  %l:%M:%S %p").gsub('-', '/')
```

> output => "02/24/2017 12:00:00 AM"

And the reverse way, assuming you have a date `mm/dd/YYYY` like: "04/27/2017" you can do:

```
actual_date_format = "02/24/2017"
date_goal = actual_date_format.split('/').reverse.join('-')
```

> output => 2017-24-02`

then

```
Date.strptime(date_goal, '%Y/%d/%m')
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am actually trying to find a solution without using such conversions. This works well if I am only using one date format (mm/dd/yyyy) but when we deploy to Canada which uses yyyy/mm/dd or dd/mm/yyyy in some provinces, I would have to replicate these conversions and account for every possible date format.

It would end up looking something like this: 
case current_user.locale
  when 'CAN-EN'
    #Do some date conversion here
  when 'CAN-FR'
    #Do another date conversion here
  when 'US-EN'
    #Do another date conversion
end